# Data labels are repeated in IE

Tags: highcharts

When i exported chart in internet explorer (version 11.0.9600.17691). As you can see in below image, data labels are repeated. I don’t have this issue when using Chrome.

[image]

Please suggest.

Comment: Could you post a live example, like jsFiddle? I am not able to recreate you issue - http://jsfiddle.net/zxp116t4/2/ Have you tried updating IE11 to 11.0.9600.18xxx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have set the **textShadow** blank and it works for me.

```
plotOptions: {
               series: {
                   grouping: true,
                   pointPadding: 0,
                   borderWidth: 0,
                   dataLabels: {
                       enabled: true,
                       crop: false,
                       formatter: function() {
                           return this.y.toFixed(1);
                       },
                       style: {
                            textShadow: ''
                       }
                   }

               }
```

Comment: This solution also helps prevent "mirrored" or "reflected" data labels when a column or bar chart is exported as a PNG, etc.